# Tailwind CSS - Extend Colors - Named Color Different?

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create some named colors from tailwind, it works however the colors aren't actually the same?!

My tailwind.config.js

```
var colorVars = function(color, brightness = 600){
  return {
    'lighter': color[brightness-200],
    'light': color[brightness-100],
    'default': color[brightness],
    'dark': color[brightness+100],
    'darker': color[brightness+200]
  };
}

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors:{
        primary: colorVars(defaultTheme.colors.indigo, 600),
      },
```

Then if I take a peek at the actual CSS I get these differences...

```
.bg-primary{
  --bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: #5a67d8;
  background-color: rgba(90, 103, 216, var(--bg-opacity));
}

.bg-indigo-600{
  --bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: #5850ec;
  background-color: rgba(88, 80, 236, var(--bg-opacity));
}
```

As you can see they are different colors, yet they should both be **indigo-600** ?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: So you don't want `.bg-primary`?

Comment: No, I don't understand why bg-primary and bg-indigo-600 are different given they should be the same?

Comment: I've worked it out, see posted answer. Let me know if you think I should refactor the question.

Comment: I don't know. Tailwind experts might understand your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this was because I was using TailwindUI and TailwindUI has a different color set from TailwindCSS hence the difference.

TailwindCSS Color Palette https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors/#default-color-palette

TailwindUI Color Palette https://tailwindui.com/documentation#how-tailwindcss-ui-extends-tailwind

To extend it I wrote this code...

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
const uiColors = require('@tailwindcss/ui/colors');

var colorVars = function(color, brightness = 600){
  return {
    'lighter': color[brightness-200],
    'light': color[brightness-100],
    'default': color[brightness],
    'dark': color[brightness+100],
    'darker': color[brightness+200]
  };
}

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors:{
        primary: colorVars(uiColors.indigo, 600),
```

See I am now taking the colors from `@tailwindcss/ui/colors` and not `tailwindcss/defaultTheme`.

Hope this also helps someone else!

Dibs to https://github.com/tailwindui/issues/issues/186 for answer also!